# Propiedad Left = 0 no coincide con el borde izquierdo de la pantalla

Tags: visual, net, basic

Estoy haciendo un programa en Visual Basic con .NET Framework 4.7.2 y necesito posicionar un formulario en las coordenadas 0, 0 a través de las propiedades Left y Top, pero ocurre algo extraño: cuando asigno el valor cero ("0") a la propiedad Left, el borde izquierdo del formulario no coincide con el borde izquierdo de la pantalla, hay una diferencia de 8 píxeles aproximadamente. Este es el código que escribí:

```
Private Sub frm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.Left = 0
    Me.Top = 0
End Sub
```

Debido a esto, para que el borde izquierdo del formulario coincida en posición con el borde izquierdo de la pantalla tengo que colocar el valor -8 a Left, y el código quedaría así:

```
Private Sub frm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.Left = -8
    Me.Top = 0
End Sub
```

Estoy trabajando bajo Windows 10, no tengo problemas con las actualizaciones ni con la resolución de la pantalla.

¿Alguien sabe por qué pasa esto?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Pero si ya lo resolviste, poner -8 es la solución